# Custom date format on PowerBI

Tags: date, format, powerbi, customization

I'm assembling data tables in PowerBI, whose rows and columns are date type, with the format that the program offers, I have managed to change the format to 'January 2018', but I want to visualize 'jan-2018', and that format is not included in the program, what should I do to get a date format like this?

I can't find any answer about my problem on any website.

The code I found is this:

```
= Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Segmento Cliente", type text}, {"Paquete", type text}, {"Fecha cosecha", type date}, {"Fecha proyectada", type date}, {"Valor", Int64.Type}})
```

I don't know what to do to change the format.
Help me please, thanks.

> EDIT: I tried this, but i get a type text column, and what I want is a type date. Any idea?

Right click your table on the right side, add new column, write code (in data or report view, not in query):

```
Custom Date = FORMAT('TABLE NAME'[TABLE COLUMN]; "FORMAT")
```

In your case the format will be MMM - YYYY

To add upper/lower case, put UPPER or LOWER before the FORMAT

Example all uppercase:

```
Custom Date = UPPER(FORMAT('TABLE NAME'[TABLE COLUMN]; "FORMAT"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Right click your table on the right side, add new column, write code (in data or report view, not in query):

```
Custom Date = FORMAT('TABLE NAME'[TABLE COLUMN]; "FORMAT")
```

In your case the format will be `MMM - YYYY`

To add upper/lower case, put `UPPER` or `LOWER` before the `FORMAT`

Example all uppercase:

```
Custom Date = UPPER(FORMAT('TABLE NAME'[TABLE COLUMN]; "FORMAT"))
```

Comment: It gives to me a column type text, what I want is a date type but with that format, is possible?

Comment: The only available formats are the ones you get to chose in PowerBI, why does it not work to use the calculated column in your visual ?

Comment: Because when i build a matrix, it orders rows and columns alphabeticaly and I don't want it, I want to order them by date

Comment: You can index the dates to sort them as you want, but i dont know how years will affect it.  I would just suggest you to use the formats Power BI is providing to ease your work.

Answer (score 0):

In the query, use this approach (for example):

```
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="WeekEnding"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}}),
WeekEnding= #"Changed Type"{0}[Column1],

WkEnding = **Date.ToText**(WeekEnding,"yyyyMMdd"),
```

This yields "20230129", in text.